# How can I print out the shortest path by using Spark Graphx

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

The following code runs well, it print out the shortest path length between two vertexes. But how can I print out the real path or the detail edges (not only the length) between two vertexes?

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SimpleGraphX").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val vertexArray = Array(
  (1L, ("Alice1", 28)),
  (2L, ("Bob2", 27)),
  (3L, ("Charlie3", 65)),
  (4L, ("David4", 42)),
  (5L, ("Ed5", 55)),
  (6L, ("Fran6", 50))
)
val edgeArray = Array(
  Edge(2L, 1L, 1),
  Edge(2L, 4L, 1),
  Edge(3L, 2L, 1),
  Edge(3L, 6L, 1),
  Edge(4L, 1L, 1),
  Edge(5L, 2L, 1),
  Edge(5L, 3L, 1),
  Edge(5L, 6L, 1)
)

val sourceId : VertexId = 5L;

val initialGraph = graph.mapVertices(
  (id,_) => if(id==sourceId)0.0 else Double.PositiveInfinity    
)

val sssp = initialGraph.pregel(Double.PositiveInfinity)(
    (id, dist, newDist) => math.min(dist, newDist),
    triplet =>{
      if(triplet.srcAttr + triplet.attr < triplet.dstAttr){
        Iterator((triplet.dstId, triplet.srcAttr+triplet.attr))
      }else{
        Iterator.empty
      }
    },
    (a,b) => math.min(a,b)
)    

println(sssp.vertices.collect.mkString("\n"))
```

When ran the code, it output the shortest path length from VertexId=5 and other vertexes, as follows:

```
(4,2.0)
(1,2.0)
(6,1.0)
(3,1.0)
(5,0.0)
(2,1.0)
```

for example, the result (4,2.0) means the shortest path length between vertex 5 and vertex 4 is 2. But I hope it could print out the detail path, such as: 5->2->4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use graphFrame.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{ArrayType, StringType, StructType, StructField, DoubleType}
import org.graphframes._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import org.graphframes.lib.Pregel
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.struct
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row


var vertex_df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("/home/tm/Documents/vertex1.csv")
val edge_df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("/home/tm/Documents/edge1.csv")
spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("/home/tm/checkpoints")

var graph = GraphFrame(vertex_df, edge_df)

val inDegrees=graph.inDegrees
val outDegrees=graph.outDegrees

vertex_df = vertex_df.join(outDegrees,outDegrees("id") ===  vertex_df("id"), "left").join(inDegrees, inDegrees("id") === vertex_df("id"), "left").select(vertex_df("id"), vertex_df("name"), outDegrees("outDegree"), inDegrees("inDegree"))

vertex_df = vertex_df.withColumn("nodeType", when(col("inDegree").isNull,"root").otherwise(when(col("outDegree").isNull,"leaf").otherwise("child")))

graph = GraphFrame(vertex_df, edge_df)

val root_node = 5

val vertColSchema = StructType(
  List(
    StructField("dist", DoubleType, true),
    StructField("name", StringType, true),
    StructField("path", ArrayType(StringType), true)
  )
)

def vertexProgram(vd: Row, msg:Row): (Double, String, WrappedArray[String]) ={
    if (msg == null || vd(0).asInstanceOf[Double] < msg(0).asInstanceOf[Double])
    {
        (vd(0).asInstanceOf[Double], vd(1).asInstanceOf[String], vd(2).asInstanceOf[WrappedArray[String]])
    }
    else
    {
        (msg(0).asInstanceOf[Double], vd(1).asInstanceOf[String], msg(2).asInstanceOf[WrappedArray[String]])
    }
}

val vertexProgramUdf = udf(vertexProgram _)


def sendMsgToDst(src:Row, dst:Row): (Double, String, WrappedArray[String]) = {
    val srcDist = src(0)
    val dstDist = dst(0)

    if (srcDist.asInstanceOf[Double] < (dstDist.asInstanceOf[Double] - 1))
    {
        (srcDist.asInstanceOf[Double] + 1, src(1).asInstanceOf[String], src(2).asInstanceOf[WrappedArray[String]] :+ dst(1).asInstanceOf[String])
    }
    else { 
        null
    }
}

val sendMsgToDstUdf = udf(sendMsgToDst _)


def aggMsgs(agg: WrappedArray[Row]): (Double, String, WrappedArray[String]) = {
(agg(0)(0).asInstanceOf[Double], agg(0)(1).asInstanceOf[String], agg(0)(2).asInstanceOf[WrappedArray[String]])
}

val aggMsgsUdf = udf(aggMsgs _)

val dbl:Double = 0.0

val result = graph.pregel.setMaxIter(3).withVertexColumn(colName = "vertCol",
initialExpr = when(col("id")===(lit(root_node)), struct(lit(dbl), col("id"), array(col("id"))))
.otherwise(struct(lit(Double.PositiveInfinity), col("id"), array(lit("")))).cast(vertColSchema),
updateAfterAggMsgsExpr = vertexProgramUdf(col("vertCol"), Pregel.msg)).sendMsgToDst(sendMsgToDstUdf(col("src.vertCol"), Pregel.dst("vertCol"))).aggMsgs(aggMsgsUdf(collect_list(Pregel.msg))).run()

scala> result.show()
+---+-------+---------+--------+--------+-------------------+
| id|   name|outDegree|inDegree|nodeType|            vertCol|
+---+-------+---------+--------+--------+-------------------+
|  1|  Alice|     null|       2|    leaf|[2.0, 1, [5, 2, 1]]|
|  2|    Bob|        2|       2|   child|   [1.0, 2, [5, 2]]|
|  3|Charlie|        2|       1|   child|   [1.0, 3, [5, 3]]|
|  4|  David|        1|       1|   child|[2.0, 4, [5, 2, 4]]|
|  5|     Ed|        3|    null|    root|      [0.0, 5, [5]]|
|  6|   Fran|     null|       2|    leaf|   [1.0, 6, [5, 6]]|
+---+-------+---------+--------+--------+-------------------+
```

Comment: thanks, graphframe is one way, I also figured out another way with less code.

Comment: @Hegde Can you use shortest path algorithm without actually using Pregel? Example, For each name find the nearest node. Not only from one Name to others! Is it possible to do without using Pregel?